# Django: What's the point to have 2-items tuples for the LANGUAGES setting?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-settings

In the project's settings file, if we want to restrict language choices for i18n, we are supposed to write this:

```
gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('Fr', gettext('French')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

but I write this:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', 'cool dudes'),
    ('en', 'Anglais')
    )
```

Whatever I put in the second item of the tuples (with "gettext = lambda s: s" or not), Django brings back "Français" and "English" in my language selector in a rendered page… I've also tried to raw language data in that selector's captions:

```
{'code':'fr', 'name':'French', 'bidi':False, 'name_local':u'Fran\xe7ais'}
{'code':'en', 'name':'English', 'bidi':False, 'name_local':u'English'}
```

It puzzles me, so what's the point to have 2-items tuples for this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Django documentation for *Settings*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#languages) describes this second value and how to use it.

> ...With this arrangement, django-admin.py makemessages will still find and mark these strings for translation, but the translation won't happen at runtime -- so you'll have to remember to wrap the languages in the real gettext() in any code that uses LANGUAGES at runtime.

The second string in the two-tuple is intended to be a human-readable rendition of the language name. Wrap the second value in a call to `gettext()` in order to mark them as translatable strings. But the normal implementation of `gettext()` isn't available in the settings module, so you have to define a dummy implementation, as your code shows. If you want the language name localised, you do need to wrap the value in the actual `gettext()` at the point of use.

You don't show your template code for the language selector UI. Are you using [`get_language_info()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#localized-names-of-languages)? The example the docs give doesn't show it, but it looks to me like you'd need to wrap the `name_local` element in `_()`. (But I haven't tested this.)

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language_info
li = get_language_info('de')
print(li['name'], _(li['name_local']), li['bidi'])
```